# Weasyprint font issue leads to all characters being replaced by boxes

Tags: html, pdf, weasyprint

I've installed weasyprint using `pip install weasyprint`, which, in my understanding, should install the necessary dependencies.

Somehow, the PDF output generated by weasyprint does not contain any fonts and all characters are replaced by boxes.

When opening the document, I can see that no fonts are embedded. I can also reproduce the problem by entering `python -m weasyprint.navigator` in Terminal and accessing one of the example sites. Below is the wikipedia home page rendered by my weasyprint installation.

[image: Wikipedia homepage rendered with weasyprint]

What could be causing this problem and how could I go about solving it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/314

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is with font. Probably, you do not have the right fonts installed in the server. In linux (ubuntu) you can run this command to install recommended fonts using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

To manage your fonts, you use:

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and google lead me to this topic. I want to confirm that the problem was with missing fonts in my Linux Docker image.

Install the missing font to your system. On my OS there weren't any fonts installed.

Comment: The question was also *how could I go about solving it?*. Can you please provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: It is specific to the OS you use. Add missing fonts to your system. In my case, I did it with `apk --update add fontconfig ttf-dejavu` But I am not sure it can help to the author of this topic. @colidyre

Comment: But you indeed helped me. Also using docker and missed the fact that my image build with no fonts at all. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, I think the lack of fonts caused this problem, and finally I added a font in the `/usr/share/fonts/`folder to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue on MacOS using `fc-*` command line tools. You can install them with `brew install fontconfig`.

1. Run `fc-list` to list fonts installed on the system
2. Run `fc-cache -v` to see places where fontconfig looks for fonts on the system
3. Pick one of these locations (if it doesn't exist then make it) and copy font(s) there.

```
# note: change `alex` to your user name
sudo mkdir /Users/alex/.fonts
sudo cp /Library/Fonts/Microsoft\ Sans\ Serif.ttf /Users/alex/.fonts
```

4. Re-generate the cache with `fc-cache -vf`
5. Check that font has been installed by running `fc-list`
6. PDF should now generate properly